# How to get a continuously changing user input dependent output in the same place at command line

Tags: python, string, input, output

I am designing a string based game where the real time positions of characters are represented as a *string* as follows:
    `-----A-----o-----`
I am changing the position of the character "A" based upon user keyboard inputs
eg:
updated position:
    `--------A--o-----`

I don't want to print the *string* line by line as It gets updated instead I want to modify it every time in the same place when being output in command line, as the constraint I am working with is :

The entire game map should run on a single line on the command line -
changing the state of the game should not spawn a new line every time.

Comment: Can you show the code? So someone can help you

Answer (score 0):

You could use '\r' in some way. Carriage return is a control character or mechanism used to reset a device's position to the beginning of a line of text. e.g.

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i, end="\r");
```

Example including controls

```
import time
import keyboard

# params
size = 20
position = 0

# game loop
while True:
    # draw
    print("", end="\r")
    for i in range(size):
        print("-" if (position != i) else "o", end="")
    # move
    if keyboard.is_pressed("left"):  
        position = position - 1
        if position < 0:
            position = 0
    elif keyboard.is_pressed("right"):  
        position = position + 1
        if position >= size:
            position = size
    # delay    
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: can you please explain what is the sleep function doing, how does it clear the last pressed  key value ,because without it ,the program runs based on the last pressed key

Comment: @mkj In this example, the sleep function specifies the cycle in which the pressed key is evaluated. There is no event that the key was pressed.
 We determine here only whether the key is pressed or not. Let's assume that a looping cycle lasts 10ms. If you press the button for 100ms the button press would be counted 10 times. To prevent this we use a delay. If you set the sleep to e.g. 1s the keystroke will be counted only every second. If you don't want to use a delay you have to remember the state and only do an action when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

when printing the output use the **end** attribute for print statements and set it as "\r" to get back the output position to starting of the line.